# Rounding UP a number to 3 decimal places in C programming

Tags: c

I am trying to round UP my data to 3 decimal places but it does not work properly.
The code i have written is:

```
//Check and round up raw data
printf(" --- ROUNDED DATA ---\n");
for (rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < MAX_ROWS; rowIndex++)
{
    // Read up until the last value
    for (columnIndex = 0; columnIndex < MAX_COLUMNS; columnIndex++)
    {
        if (rawData[rowIndex][columnIndex] < rangeValue1)
            printf("%.3f ", rangeValue1);
        else if (rawData[rowIndex][columnIndex] > rangeValue2)
            printf("%.3f ", rangeValue2);
        else
            printf("%.3f ", rawData[rowIndex][columnIndex]);
    }

    printf("\n");
}
```

rangeValue1 is a variable defined as 0 and rangeValue2 is defined as 2.5 .
I tried ceil function but the problem is that it rounds up the number for example 1.5555 to 2.000. what i want is to round UP the number to 1.556. I put the function ceil before rawData in the second last sentence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move decimal point to where you want to round up, do round up and move it back.

```
ceil(value * 1000.0) / 1000.0
```

Answer (score 0):

You could simply multiply your float value by 1000 and `ceil` it and then divide by 1000 to achieve your desired value.

`ceil(data * 1000.0) / 1000.0`